# Notify key stakeholders (reporter) when work item or user story is completed

Tags: notifications, azure-devops

I'm not sure if this is currently possible but I haven't been able to find a way to do this yet.

We are still getting adjusted to our VSTS flow and when we setup some of our cards we are setting who the Reporters are so we can identify key stakeholders. I'm wondering if it is possible to setup some kind of rule that triggers when a user story or work item is completed to send an email notification to the reporter. Oh I should also mention that most of these individuals will not have VSTS accounts either.

Also if this is not currently a feature with VSTS where do you usually request features from Microsoft? Is it on their corresponding Github page and you create an issue or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the reporter seems is the person who **Assigned To** the work item.

So you can add notifications to the user’s email when WIT state changed to completed and the WIT is Assigned to the user. Detail settings as below:

In the notification page -> new subscription -> select A work item is created -> specify the email address -> Add the filter State changes to Completed and Assigned To = user name -> Save.

**Note:** username in Assigned To operation should be the display name. Such as a user display name is marina liu, you should specify marina liu in the Assigned To value.

[image]
[image]

Besides, request features for VSTS can be posted [user voices](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services). If you have a new idea or the require the features which VSTS not contains, you can add an user voice for it.

Comment: I think you missed the mark on this. The question was about the person that reported the issue (stakeholder / reporter), not the person that will resolve the issue (Assigned To).